# Correspendence between list indices originated from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indices

I wrote the below code working with dictionary and list:

```
d = computeRanks() # dictionary of id : interestRank pairs
lst = list(d) # tuples (id, interestRank)
interestingIds = []
for i in range(20): # choice randomly 20 highly ranked ids
  choice = randomWeightedChoice(d.values()) # returns random index from list
  interestingIds.append(lst[choice][0])
```

There seems to be possible error because I'm not sure if there is a correspondence between indices in *lst* and *d.values()*.

Do you know how to write this better?

Comment: Why do you need `lst`? You can randomly select a key from the `d` (using `d.keys()`) and add that to `interestingIds`.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I can't do this because it's random with weights and weigths are interestRanks which are in *d.values()*.

Comment: what is the type of `d`?

Comment: @alexis list of (int, float) tuples

Comment: Then @Simeon is right, `list(d)` is exactly the same as `d`.

Comment: But actually that's not possible: Lists don't have a `values()` method. `d` is not a list.

Comment: @alexis Sorry I wrote the type of lst above. The type of `d` is dictionary of int : float pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the policies of `dict` is that the results of `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` will correspond *so long as the contents of the dictionary are not modified*.

Comment: I didn't say that. But this part wouldn't change a lot.

Comment: You showed that `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` correspond, but in the question is `lst(dict)` instead of `dict.keys()`. Does this make a difference?

Comment: No. Iterating over a `dict` via `list(dict)` defers to `dict.iterkeys()`, which [is part of the same policy](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Comment: Oh, as for the rewrite, you should modify randomWeightedChoice(). Think of what sorted() and max() do.

Comment: Rewrite is not problem but I wanted to go without rewrite because I'm using this function mainly for lists and don't want to create new function for each special data structure.

Comment: This rewrite will generalize the function to any iterable.

Comment: I guess you have some design pattern on mind but have no idea how to generalize it for every data structure. You still have to specify where is a list of values in that data structure, I think.

Comment: Correct. Which is why I brought up those examples.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ignacio says, the index `choice` does correspond to the intended element of `lst`, so your code's logic is correct. But your code should be much simpler: `d` already contains IDs for the elements, so rewrite `randomWeightedChoice` to take a dictionary and return an ID.

Perhaps it will help you to know that you can iterate over a dictionary's key-value pairs with `d.items()`:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    etc.
```

Comment: *randomWeightedChoice* takes a list and returns an index from this list. It won't be rewritten. I need to generate exactly 20 random numbers so don't need to iterate over all key-value pairs.

Comment: You don't have to iterate, that was a demonstration. `randomWeightedChoice` needs to examine all the values in order to do its job, so it has a loop somewhere. If you can't rewrite it, I don't think there's anything else we can help with.

Comment: Yes, *randomWeightedChoice* needs to examine all the values 20 times to choose 20 random values.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only has to examine them once. But what does it matter, if you won't be rewriting it?

Comment: If I would rewrite this question would have no sense. I'd like to have unique interface instead of having the same function for various data structures (dicts, lists, sets etc.).